# javascript calendar not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have JavaScript Calendar in my web page.

The following code is not working:

```
<td> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_datefrm" runat="server" Width="71px"></asp:TextBox> 
  <a href="javascript:OpenCalFuture('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_datefrm');">
                      <img src="cal.gif"  border="0" height="16" width="16"/></a>

</td>
```

Any idea on what could have gone wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: And why doesnt it work? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Is the OpenCalFuture method defined somewhere? For this to work, it'd have to be a javascript function defined on your page, or in a script file that is referenced by your page. Did you perhaps copy this code from an example or another page, and forget to copy the reference? Also, I should probably mention that this looks a lot like old-school calendar code which pops open new windows. These are generally frowned upon these days (for a variety of good reasons - one of them being that the browser might block your popup attempt, leaving a confused user or developer). You'd be better off trying s

Comment: Your question does not include enough information for anyone to be of any real help. Please include more of your code so we can see what the OpenCalFuture method is, what the calendar should be, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the UniqueID instead of hardcoding the ID:

```
OpenCalFuture('<%=txt_datefrm.UniqueID%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a small pop-up calendar, to make it easier for the user to pop a date string into a text field, you should really give [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) a try.  It's an excellent tool (all of jquery is, really)

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<asp:Calendar id="MyCalendar" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

It looks to me like you're trying to instantiate a C# class in a javascript code block.